# A dimmer onto a circuit that controls the top receptacle of 2 plugs and also two led pot lights?

Tags: wiring

I'm wondering if, because the light switch turns on and off the top receptacle on a wall plug,  can you still install a dimmer on this circuit?

Thanks
 j-bob8

Answer (score 2):

NEC prohibits standards receptacles from being on dimmed circuits. Lutron makes a dimmable receptacle that ordinary plugs will not go into, but which is designed to be on a dimmed circuit. If you actually want to plug something into the dimmed receptacle, they sell a custom plug that you can wire yourself.

If you don't actually care about making a dimmable receptacle, there's nothing as far as I know that prohibits you from capping (or if the dimmed circuit runs through the receptacle box, joining together) the dimmed conductor in the box and just replacing it with a standard duplex receptacle powered by the non-dimmed circuit already present there. The end result is that you have two pot lights on your dimmer on a circuit that happens to run through but does nothing to your receptacle box.